# Google Account shows two Android Login Service in Connected Sites, Apps, and Services

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-account, htc-one-x, authorization

I have a HTC One X and when I go to my Google account's Security section -> Connected Sites, Apps and Services, it shows me two entries of "Android Login Service — Full Account Access". But I have only one Android device. Below is the screenshot:

[image: Connected Sites, Apps and Services]

Is this correct or there is another device which connected to my account?

Answer (score 1):

"Android Login Service" will show up if you use the browser login.Revoking it will prevent the device from logging in, phone will ask for password.

Just to see I went into my **account>security>connected apps** and revoked access to everything that started with android(In my account also there were two entries). Phone ask me to sign in again and everything's working so I'd say do the same. I don't think you're hacked but still, it certainly couldn't hurt.

Link to [discussion about accesses](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101870690807496858960/posts/h3PjjXqM9J4)

Comment: I revoked access to one of my Android Login Service then both of them disappeared. Then I logged into my Android device and Android Login Service again showed up but now only one entry shows. I logged in using the default browser (on Android) but it still shows only one entry for Android Login Service. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But what does "browser login" exactly mean?